Multiple BadZipFile errors while installing any project on WSL
I have setup WSL on my new Windows 11 PC. However, when I try to install any linux project (e.g. Stable Diffusion), I get multiple BadZipFile CRC-32 errors. This happens for almost every project that I try to install on my WSL. I thought there might be an issue with my Windows disk hence I set up a new WSL installation on an external hard drive but still face the same issue. If I try to run the same setup again, there is a new file that has this error.
As an example, I tried installing Stable Diffusion Webui. However, I get a zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad CRC-32 everytime I try to install. This happens if I try installing any other project too.
Here is the error log of one such installation attempt. Any idea what is causing the badzip file error if it is not hard disk issue?
Update - the issue seems to be with pip throwing this error randomly for different packages. No idea why.

Collecting mpmath<1.4.0,>=1.1.0
  Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/mpmath-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (536 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 536.2/536.2 kB 10.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: mpmath, urllib3, typing-extensions, sympy, pillow, numpy, networkx, MarkupSafe, idna, fsspec, filelock, charset-normalizer, certifi, triton, requests, jinja2, torch, torchvision
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sdp/stable-diffusion-webui/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 167, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "/home/sdp/stable-diffusion-webui/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/home/sdp/stable-diffusion-webui/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 461, in run
    installed = install_given_reqs(
  File "/home/sdp/stable-diffusion-webui/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 73, in install_given_reqs
    requirement.install(
  File "/home/sdp/stable-diffusion-webui/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 790, in install
    install_wheel(
  File "/home/sdp/stable-diffusion-webui/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/install/wheel.py", line 727, in install_wheel
    _install_wheel(
  File "/home/sdp/stable-diffusion-webui/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/install/wheel.py", line 587, in _install_wheel
    file.save()
  File "/home/sdp/stable-diffusion-webui/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/install/wheel.py", line 388, in save
    shutil.copyfileobj(f, dest)
  File "/home/sdp/miniconda3/envs/sd/lib/python3.10/shutil.py", line 195, in copyfileobj
    buf = fsrc_read(length)
  File "/home/sdp/miniconda3/envs/sd/lib/python3.10/zipfile.py", line 925, in read
    data = self._read1(n)
  File "/home/sdp/miniconda3/envs/sd/lib/python3.10/zipfile.py", line 1015, in _read1
    self._update_crc(data)
  File "/home/sdp/miniconda3/envs/sd/lib/python3.10/zipfile.py", line 943, in _update_crc
    raise BadZipFile("Bad CRC-32 for file %r" % self.name)
zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad CRC-32 for file 'torch/include/ATen/ops/view_as_complex_copy.h'

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.2.1 -> 24.1
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sdp/stable-diffusion-webui/launch.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/sdp/stable-diffusion-webui/launch.py", line 39, in main
    prepare_environment()
  File "/home/sdp/stable-diffusion-webui/modules/launch_utils.py", line 380, in prepare_environment
    run(f'"{python}" -m {torch_command}', "Installing torch and torchvision", "Couldn't install torch", live=True)
  File "/home/sdp/stable-diffusion-webui/modules/launch_utils.py", line 115, in run
    raise RuntimeError("\n".join(error_bits))
RuntimeError: Couldn't install torch.
Command: "/home/sdp/stable-diffusion-webui/venv/bin/python3" -m pip install torch==2.1.2 torchvision==0.16.2 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121
Error code: 2

